# What is the probability that A wins at or before the n-th hole?

Tags: probability

The problem is
Two golfers A and B play a series of holes. A wins each hole with probability p, B
wins each hole with probability q and holes are halved with probability r, for some p, q, r > 0 with
p + q + r = 1. Holes are independent and the game stops on the first occasion when a hole is not
halved.What is the probability that A wins at or before the n-th hole?

I know how to find the probality that A wins and this is 
p/(p+q).

Can you help me solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

$A$ wins at or before the $n$th hole with probability
$$p+rp+r^2p+... +r^{n-1}p$$

This is a Geometric Series with sum $$p\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you explain me why?

Comment: Are you happy with the LHS of the equation or should I explain that?

Comment: I would be grateful if you explain it!!

Comment: A wins after any sequence such as tied,tied,...,tied, win. The probability of such a sequence is the product of $r$s for each tied hole and $p$ for the final won hole.

Comment: So, if we say that An is the event that A wins the n-hole and Hn the event that is tied. We are looking for the P(H1 ∩ H2..... ∩ An)?

Comment: That's right. We have to add the probabilities of all these from having no $H$s to having $n-1$ of them.

Comment: yes but are they independent events right? So is this P(H1)P(H2)....P(An)=(r^n)p  ?

Comment: Your post says that the holes are independent.

Comment: Yes so doesn't this mean that P(H1)P(H2)....P(An) is the probability that i am looking for?

Comment: That's the probability of winning at the $n$th hole but you asked for "at or before"

Comment: Ok i think that i understand now how it works!!

Comment: Can you help me also with these question: What is the probability that the first hole was halved given that A wins at or before the n-th hole? Do i have to use Baye's law?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you must do.

Comment: So, if A is the event that A wins at or before the n-th hole and H1 is the event that 1st hole is halved we are looking for P(H1|A)=P(H1A)/P(A)= P(H1)P(A|H1)/P(A) .But how we find P(A|H1)?